# How Can I configure Category parameters in TeamCity to run against specific category mentioned in my project

Tags: teamcity, visual-studio-2022, cicd

I'm trying to run tests by defining category as **cat==Test1** in **Parameters | Configure parameters | Test.NunitFilterCategory** in TeamCity. But after running this build it runs all the tests.

In my class I'm using -
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestCategory("Test1")]

Please guide how can I run tests which contains only **Test1** category in Teamcity build?